# Stripping filename and linenumber from exception message in Lua

Tags: string, exception, lua, match

Im having trouble stripping out the params I need in my exception message in Lua.
The message I get looks something like the following:

```
/path/anotherpath/class.lua:929: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
```

What I want to do is to extract the name of the class (the word before ".lua") and the line number (the number after the first ":") 
Could anyone help me find the patters I need to be used in string.match?

Comment: @Egor And if not you'll *post* an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a slightly more complete answer than what Egor had (which looks correct with the caveat that it requires a .lua file extension):

```
value = "/path/anotherpath/class.lua:929: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)"
filename, linenumstring = value:match(".-([^/:\\]-)%.lua:(%d+):")
linenum = tonumber(linenumstring)
```